# Erro ao criar números de série - "O registo já existe na tabela 'dbo.LinhasNumSerie'. "

Tags: vb.net

Boa tarde, estou a ter um problema ao transformar uma ECF, quando adiciono os números de série à linha. Se adicionar apenas 1 funciona perfeitamente... O que estou a fazer mal?

```
Dim numeroserie As New GcpBENumeroSerie
Dim numerosserie As New GcpBENumerosSerie

For Each dtrow As DataRow In Session("dtNumSerie").Select("NumLinha = '" & numlinha & "'")

   numeroserie.Manual = 1
   numeroserie.Modulo = "C"
   numeroserie.NumeroSerie = dtrow("NumSerie")

   numerosserie.Insere(numeroserie)

Next

objDocCompra.Linhas(objDocCompra.Linhas.NumItens).NumerosSerie = numerosserie
```

Comment: Eu acho que é por causa da instância fora do `for` coloque a linha `Dim numeroserie As New GcpBENumeroSerie` dentro do `for` para que seja uma nova instância sempre, teste!

Comment: Resolveu, obrigado!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Dim numerosserie As New GcpBENumerosSerie
For Each dtrow As DataRow In Session("dtNumSerie").Select("NumLinha = '" & numlinha & "'")
   Dim numeroserie As New GcpBENumeroSerie
   numeroserie.Manual = 1
   numeroserie.Modulo = "C"
   numeroserie.NumeroSerie = dtrow("NumSerie")
   numerosserie.Insere(numeroserie)
Next
objDocCompra.Linhas(objDocCompra.Linhas.NumItens).NumerosSerie = numerosserie
```